# Does flash video in browser required video codecs?

Tags: video, flash, codec

Imagine situation when I don't have any video codecs and flash installed on my PC. I've downloaded and installed flash player from [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/). Can I start watching video in the web, or additional codecs (for mp4 and flv) required to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can watch videos from most sites with Flash. No other codecs are need on most sites. A few sites might tell you you need to download additional codecs to view the video, but those are usually fake sites that will install malware.

Also if you install a video player like VLC, it will add some codecs for various sites that don't rely on Flash.

Comment: Could you please provide a proof link? Customers wanted to know that no additional codecs required and I have to proof this fact.

Comment: Here is a short tutorial on codecs. It shows that most sites use the standard H.264 and MP3, so they can be encoded with Flash.

http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/streaming-101-the-basics---codecs-bandwidth-data-rate-and-resolution.html

But if any of your customers plan to use Netflix, they will need to install Silverlight as well. Only a handful of sites will require specific applications.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. It depends on what the FLV contains. The Flash player can't decode H.264 without additional codecs AFAIK. Only native Flash video is supported.